# Gitlab CI running grunt from local file system

Tags: git, gruntjs, phantomjs, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm running a grunt command via Gitlab CI, so this automatically:

- Clones my repository into a local folder (not part of my web server's public folder)
- runs `npm install` and then `grunt test`

The issue I have is that the "phantom" page needs a host to reference when requesting files from grunt's `spec` html file.

So if I pass `host: http://example.com/path-to-repo/` then it loads properly, but this defeats the purpose of CI, since i need it to act as if the recently built folder is the web page.

Hopefully this makes sense and someone can help explain how to get these recently built folders to be the host in grunt/jasmine/phantom

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out!

```
jasmine: {
    test: {
        src: ['src/<%= pkg.name %>.js'],
        options: {
            specs: ['spec/*-spec.js'],
            outfile: 'spec.html',
            keepRunner: true,
            host: 'http://127.0.0.1:9001/',
            vendor: ['vendor/file.js']
        }
    }
},
connect: {
   server: {
        options: {
            hostname: '127.0.0.1',
            port: 9001,
            onCreateServer: function(server, connect, options){
                console.log('***************\nonCreateServer', server, connect, options);
            }
        }
    }
},
```

I needed to use `grunt-contrib-connect` along with my `grunt-contrib-jasmine`